# STM32 I-CODE and D-CODE buses

Tags: arm, stm32, cortex-m

STM32 documentation says that the I-CODE and D-CODE buses are connected to the internal flash memory. The I-CODE bus is used to fetch instructions and the D-CODE bus is used for data access in the code memory region (literal load).

The question is why two separate buses are used? Can they provide simultaneous and absolutely independent access to flash memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from the stm32 [RM0090 Reference manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/DM00031020.pdf) (page 73), I-CODE and D-CODE busses cannot access the flash memory independently, they do however access the flash interface independently:

[image]

As to why there are two: they have separate chaches, also the I-CODE bus implements prefetch, which would be useless for data fetching. Relevant part of the reference manual (page 84):

> **Data management**
>
> Literal pools are fetched from Flash memory through
>   the D-Code bus during the execution  stage of the CPU pipeline. The
>   CPU pipeline is consequently stalled until the requested  literal pool
>   is provided. To limit the time lost due to literal pools, accesses
>   through the AHB  databus D-Code have priority over accesses through
>   the AHB instruction bus I-Code.  If some literal pools are frequently
>   used, the data cache memory can be enabled by setting  the data cache
>   enable (DCEN) bit in the FLASH_ACR register. This feature works like
>   the  instruction cache memory, but the retained data size is limited
>   to 8 rows of 128 bits.